# Getting an error while trying to run dbt under a venv

Tags: dbt

I have created a venv for my project. I have installed the dbt package. When I try to dbt run, I get this error.

[image]

Comment: When I remove model-paths and seed-paths from my dbt_project.yml, it works. Also If I am not using the venv, it works without removing them

Comment: what is outputted when you run `dbt --version`? My guess is your project is dbt-core>=1.0.0 and the venv version of dbt-core is <1.0.0. or vise versa

Answer (score 3):

what is outputted when you run `dbt --version`? My guess is your project is dbt-core>=1.0.0 and the venv version of dbt-core is <1.0.0. or vise versa

Answer (score 1):

Seem like a version mismatch.

`model-paths` and `seed-paths` were renamed after v1.0.0.